# VLOOKUP to replace Names

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with all the cellphone numbers of users that has phones allocated to them.
[image: USER LIST]

Then I have a sheet with all the billing information that I received from the Service Provider.
[image: BILLING INFO]

As you can see the NAME above is not the name of the user.

I need a VLOOKUP formula, that will lookup the number in the **USERLIST**, and then take the **NAME** in userlist and replace the **NAME** in BILLING INFO.

TIA,
Martin.

Comment: Swap the name and number columns in the first sheet.

Comment: O_o

But why????

Comment: If you don't want to swap columns then you can use INDEX/MATCH but you need to show the formula you've tried.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` searches the left column for a key, and then can return the right column as the response.  Your columns are in the wrong order.  Also, your question is too vague for an exact formula to be given IMO.

Comment: =VLOOKUP(D6,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$1:$C$1000,2,FALSE)

Here is a formula I tried, but returns a #REF!

Comment: D6 being the NUMBER in column B on **USERLIST**

Comment: =VLOOKUP(D6,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$1:$C$1000,1,FALSE)

This only returns the number. Where I want the NAME returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `MATCH` function (looking in the second column of the table) to find the row in the table.

For example: If your user list is in range A3:B6 on Sheet1, you could use:

```
=MATCH(C3,Sheet1!$B$3:$B$6,0)
```

to find the row you need.

You can use that row in the `INDEX` function to get the actual value:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$3:$B$6,MATCH(C3,Sheet1!$B$3:$B$6,0),1)
```

---

Edit:

I just noticed that shrivallabha.redij had already suggested this an hour ago in a comment, so the credit should go to him/her.

And of course, this solution does not use `VLOOKUP` as the OP asked. So swapping the columns (as Tim Biegeleisen suggested) might be better. Or simply add a third column which refers to the 1st column ...

Comment: '=MATCH(D7,MTN USER LIST!$C$1:$C$1000,0)'


When using the above, I get #NAME? error.


'=INDEX(UserList,MATCH(D7,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$1000,0),1)'

When using the above, I get the same error

Comment: Regarding that first error: You should use `=MATCH(D7,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$1:$C$1000,0)` rather than `=MATCH(D7,MTN USER LIST!$C$1:$C$1000,0)` because your sheet name contains spaces.

Comment: `=INDEX(UserList,MATCH(D9,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$6,0),1)`


This looks like what I need, but does not return the correct "answer".
Keep receiving #NAME? error, even after some reviewing to make sure its correct.

Comment: @JPMV - are you using Excel with an "English" locale?

Comment: Thanks for helping @Peter Pesch.
Much much appreciated.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes with English Locale. But I know for sure this is an "error".

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(D6,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$1:$C$1000,1,FALSE)` When using **this**, it just returns the number, but not the NAME.

Comment: @Tim @JPMV Error was that my code still contained the name `UserList` which I used while examining JPMV's question. Updated my answer.

Comment: `=INDEX(UserList,MATCH(D9,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$6,0),1)` I think this one just needs some fine tuning. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @PeterPesch I now see what you mean. 
`=INDEX(**UserList**,MATCH(D9,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$6,0),1)`

Is the ** ** where my issue lies?

Comment: @JPMV: As @TimBiegeleisen already explained, `VLOOKUP` can only give results from columns to the right side of the lookup column. So if you want to kooj up a number using `VLOOKUP` and get the name as a reult, you need to have the number column to the left side of the name column.

Comment: Yes. the ** ** is where your issue (my error)  lies.

Comment: @JPMV `=INDEX('MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$C$1000,MATCH(C3,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$1000,0),1)` should work, I think. Still I think that Tim Biegeleisen's idea would be better ...

Comment: @PeterPesch please advise. Im still not getting this formula to work...

Comment: What is your current formula? What is the exact error you are getting? What is the address of the cell whose value you are trying to lookup? What is the exact address of your user list? Have you read and understood each of the 19 comments so far?

Comment: Yes I have understood all the comments. 
The address of the cell I'm trying to lookup is all in column B. (Names)

To try make it easier:

If the telephone number in **"Mobile Data and Airtime,D6"** matches any number in **"MTN USER LIST,C1:C1000"**, it must return the NAME that is in front (in column B) of the matched number.

Comment: `=INDEX('MTN USER LIST'!****,MATCH(D6,'MTN USER LIST'!C4:'MTN USER LIST'!C1000,0),1)`

Here is my current formula. I still need to replace the **** as you said that was where my error was.

Comment: And what is the exact error that you get if you try `=INDEX('MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$C$1000,MATCH(D6,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$1000,0),1)` again?

Comment: In lookup functions, `#N/A` usually means that it cannot find the value. What is the exact value in cell D6? And are you sure that value exists in column B of sheet `MTN USER LIST` ? And on which row does it occur?

Comment: The value in D6 is the telephone number. I did a "find" search of the value in D6 on MTN USER LIST, and was able to find it in C87.

Comment: So, the name I will want to have returned, will be in B87.

Comment: What do you get if you put `=('Mobile Data and Airtime'!D6='MTN USER LIST'!C87)` in a cell?

Comment: And what do you get if you put `=MATCH('Mobile Data and Airtime'!D16,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$1002,0)` in a cell?

Comment: for `=('Mobile Data and Airtime'!D6='MTN USER LIST'!C87)` I get TRUE

Comment: For `=MATCH('Mobile Data and Airtime'!D16,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$1002,0)` I get #N/A again

Comment: And if you put `=MATCH('Mobile Data and Airtime'!D6,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$1002,0)` in a cell?

Comment: When I do a "find" for the value in D16 on 'MTN USER LIST', I am able to find the number.

Comment: For `=MATCH('Mobile Data and Airtime'!D6,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$1002,0)`  I get **85**

Comment: I see for `=MATCH('Mobile Data and Airtime'!D16,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$1002,0)` I get **70**

Comment: 85 is correct. Now what do you get if you put `=INDEX('MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$C$1000,85,1)` in a cell?

Comment: For `=INDEX('MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$C$1000,85,1)` I get the name **"Martin Chibulaluko"**

Comment: So `=MATCH('Mobile Data and Airtime'!D6,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$1002,0)` gives 85, and `=INDEX('MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$C$1000,85,1)` gives `Martin Chibulaluko` ...

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that sure that `=INDEX('MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$C$1000,MATCH('Mobile Data and Airtime'!D6,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$1002,0),1)` does not give a result? (We already established that the outer half and the inner half both do work ...)

Comment: I **now** get the name "Martin Chibulaluko", BUT, when I 'drag' down the formula to apply to the cells below, its again gives me a #N/A

Comment: Could you copy the formula from the row that is 10 rows below the original formula, and paste it here?

Comment: `=INDEX('MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$B$1000,MATCH('Mobile Data and Airtime'!D16,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$1000,0),1)`

Comment: That is very strange. It should have been `=INDEX('MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$C$1000,MATCH('Mobile Data and Airtime'!D16,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$1000,0),1)`. Where did that `=INDEX('MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$B` come from, when dragging it down from a formula that starts with `=INDEX('MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$C` ???

Comment: PLEASE excuse. That is MY fault. I changed the `'MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$C$1000` to `=INDEX('MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$B` so that it only indexes from the **B** column. 
BUT even when it was as original, "`'MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$C$1000`", and I dragged the formula to the lower cells, I still received a #N/A

Comment: And, I have done a "find" for most of the numbers that returned a #N/A, and they I have every single one on the 'MTN USER LIST' sheet

Comment: Now please change it back to `=INDEX('MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$C$1000,MATCH('Mobile Data and Airtime'!D6,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$1002,0),1)` ( which gave `Martin Chibulaluko` earlier) and drag it down. What is the formula 10 rows below now?

Comment: `=INDEX('MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$C$1000,MATCH('Mobile Data and Airtime'!D16,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$1000,0),1)`

Comment: Noted one thing, in one list the numbers have been stored as text and that will give you problems. In your original post (snapshot #2), for names LUBAMBE COPPER, Peter & Dickson you will see small green triangle in the Number column which means they're stored as text. Convert them to text and your INDEX/MATCH will give fair results!

Comment: Does `=MATCH('Mobile Data and Airtime'!D16,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$1000,0)` still yield 70? If yes, please try `=INDEX('MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$C$1000,70,1)` ...

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Correct. That's why I wanted to see `=('Mobile Data and Airtime'!D6='MTN USER LIST'!C87)` earlier today. ... (But we already know that D16 will be found in row 70)

Comment: `=MATCH('Mobile Data and Airtime'!D16,'MTN USER LIST'!$C$3:$C$1000,0)` still brings **70**.
And `=INDEX('MTN USER LIST'!$B$3:$C$1000,70,1)` brings **Christopher Hara**

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij when I converted, looks like that solved the problem (facepalm). Will give final feedback in few minutes.
Thanks

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Thanks a lot for your input. Thats what the problem was.

Comment: @PeterPesch I cannot thank you enough for your input. You sir, are a legend! Thank you into eternity!